# Google Plus share issue in no network and reboot

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

Google Plus get force closed when I reboot the android device or when I turn off the network while sharing any post via google plus.

```
Uncaught exception in background thread Thread[IntentService[PicasaSyncConnectivityAsync],5,main]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cit.a(ProGuard:258)
    at cit.<init>(ProGuard:198)
    at cit.a(ProGuard:189)
    at com.google.android.picasasync.ConnectivityReceiver$AsyncService.onHandleIntent(ProGuard:38)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[PicasaSyncConnectivityAsync]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cit.a(ProGuard:258)
    at cit.<init>(ProGuard:198)
    at cit.a(ProGuard:189)
    at com.google.android.picasasync.ConnectivityReceiver$AsyncService.onHandleIntent(ProGuard:38)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Sometimes I am getting Null pointer Exception in ConnectionResult.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
     if (!mGooglePlusIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
              mIntentInProgress = true;
              result.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), ShareHelper.GOOGLE_PLUS_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
              // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
              // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
              mIntentInProgress = false;
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
     }
}
```

So I try to catch the Null pointer Exception.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
     if (!mGooglePlusIntentInProgress && result != null && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
              mIntentInProgress = true;
              result.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), ShareHelper.GOOGLE_PLUS_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
              // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
              // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
              mIntentInProgress = false;
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception is : " + e.getMessage());
            }
     }
}
```

Even after catching the exception, there is force close in Google plus. Is this an issue of google plus ?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Google Play services?

Comment: Yes.This is Google plus application issue. In low version device (2.3.3 version), when I install Google plus, this issue always produce.